# Variables in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables

I've started learning RoR and I have little issue with variables, here is my problem:

I have this partial:

```
<% if @user.errors.any? %>
    The form contains <%= pluralize($items, "error")%>
    <ul>
    <% messages = @user.errors.full_messages %>
    <% messages.delete "Password digest can't be blank" %>
    <% if messages.include? "Password can't be blank" %>
      <% messages.delete "Password confirmation can't be blank" %>
      <% messages.delete "Password is too short (minimum is 6 characters)"%>
    <% end %>
    <% messages.each do |msg|%>
      <li>* <%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
    <% $items = messages.count %>
<% end %>
```

I used the global variable `$items` to get access to the new value of the `messages`variable.
The problem is that when I refresh the page I get the old value not the new one.

What I want is being able to use the value of the variable `messages` in the method `pluralize`.

PS: I cannot change the html

Comment: Just as a helpful note, fiddling with variables like this in your template is not generally something you want to do. Ordinarily you'd do this sort of preprocessing in the controller.

Comment: Yes I think I should do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why you would want to do that, but this should fix your problem:

```
<% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <% messages = @user.errors.full_messages %>
    <% messages.delete "Password digest can't be blank" %>
    <% if messages.include? "Password can't be blank" %>
      <% messages.delete "Password confirmation can't be blank" %>
      <% messages.delete "Password is too short (minimum is 6 characters)"%>
    <% end %>
    <% items = messages.count %>
    The form contains <%= pluralize(items, "error")%>
    <ul>
    <% messages.each do |msg|%>
      <li>* <%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Worked Thanks.I'm starting with ruby and actually I wanted to know how I use a variable before it was declared.

Answer (score 1):

You want to do:

```
<%= pluralize(@user.errors.full_messages.size, "error") %>
```

Global variables will stick around between requests which is why you're seeing the old value, because you set it at the bottom of your view. You don't need to use them. Using the code above you can effectively accomplish what you seemingly want.

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't work". Error? Non pluralized word? Please provide more detail, we only mean to help!

Comment: It gave me the old value not the new one after the if statement.

Comment: Ok, try AbM's answer.

Comment: That's because you are calculating $items after calling it in your pluralize method